# Download Excel direct to drive (C:\) (No save as option require) VBA Excel

Tags: download, internet-explorer-11

I am new in VBA. Please help me to download the excel file direct in to my drive. I have only option to click the element and it prompt of "Save As" dialog box.

Application.StatusBar = "Saving - Dashboard.xlsx"
Set InputElement = doc.querySelector("span.export[class='export excel'")

```
    If Not InputElement Is Nothing Then

    InputElement.Click
```

I am running this code every hour, I can't click save as button every hour.

I was thinking to download auto downloader, but did not get much success. Coz, I have have admin right and out of policy.

Public Sub OpenIE_Login()

```
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate cURL



Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop ''' ATTENTION - PAUSE HERE


    Set doc = IE.Document



    Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)

    Set InputElement = doc.querySelector("input#userName[id='userName']")

    If Not InputElement Is Nothing Then
        InputElement.Value = cUsername
    End If
```

'

Set InputElement = doc.querySelector("input.field[type='password']")

```
    If Not InputElement Is Nothing Then
        InputElement.Value = cPassword
    End If

Application.StatusBar = "Saving - WokingHours.xlsx"
```

Set InputElement = doc.querySelector("span.export[class='export excel'")
'Dim TempStr As String
        If Not InputElement Is Nothing Then
        'TempStr = InputElement.Value
        InputElement.Click

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not posted the code which actually downloads the file. In title of the thread, You said VBA Excel but your code using IE object.

If you have the URL of the file than you can refer example below for downloading the file.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
Sub demo()

Dim strURL As String
Dim LocalFilePath As String
Dim DownloadStatus As Long

    strURL = "http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt"
    LocalFilePath = "C:\Users\panchals\Desktop\sample.txt"
    DownloadStatus = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, LocalFilePath, 0, 0)
    If DownloadStatus = 0 Then
        MsgBox "File Downloaded. Check in this path: " & LocalFilePath
    Else
        MsgBox "Download File Process Failed"
    End If
End Sub
```

You need to modify the code as per your own requirement.

Reference:

[Download Files with VBA URLDownloadToFile](https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/download-files-with-vba-urldownloadtofile/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!! Like I said, I am new in VBA. The code is in excel flie and when it reach at "InputElement.Click" popup comes and ask to 1.Open, 2 Save & 3 SaveAS. Is possible to save directly in to my drive?

Comment: If you have URL of the file on the time of click than you can use the above code to save the file directly to your drive. it will not show a Save As pop up to you. I suggest you to directly run the sample code to get the idea about it.

Comment: Thank you for reply, i did same as you suggest but did not get much success. In the link, extension not define (.xls)

Comment: https://nicetime.com/reports/dashboard.do?filters2[0].ie=I&unconfirmActivity=&forcedSave=false&org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN=9c2fc267c33dac3b7e18776bd079&d-1793-e=2&action=refresh&6578706f7274=1&filters3[0].high=&filters1[0].operator=EQ&filters3[0].ie=I&filters2[0].operator=EQ&filters2[0].high=&forcedQtyZero=false&filters3[0].operator=EQ&filters1[0].ie=I&filters1[0].high=&toStatusId=&filters2[0].low=&filters3[0].low=&quickSearch=&filters1[0].property=AUFNR&filters2[0].property=AUFNR&filters1[0].low=7180464&filters3[0].property=AUFNR&username=RAVI